# Is it possible to install 64 bit JVM on linux so heap can be larger then 2gb?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

It's a 32 bit Ubuntu OS

```
rob@laptop:~$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 
10 17:51:56 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


rob@laptop:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)


rob@laptop:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
0            /usr/lib/j2re1.6-ibm/jre/bin/java               1200      auto mode
1            /home/rob/Downloads/jre1.7.0_25/bin/java        1         manual mode
2            /usr/lib/j2re1.6-ibm/jre/bin/java               1200      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
```

I want to be able to run with more than 2g of heap

```
rob@laptop:~$ java -Xmx3g -jar tool.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

rob@laptop:~$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            15          2         12          0          0          1
```

Comment: Why not just install a 64-bit OS? BTW You should never try to make the heap much more than 80% of your main memory as it will perform very badly.  If you need more memory I suggest you buy it.  16 GB doesn't cost much these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A 32-bit kernel(and likely 32-bit CPU as well) cannot run a 64-bit executable for the JVM(or any other 64-bit executable/ELF) with your choice of OS and kernel.

Comment: ... or any other 64 bit executable for that matter.

Comment: For Linux.  This is true even if the processor can run 64 bit code,  you need 64bit Ubuntu then.

Answer (score 0):

As far I see, you do not mention what hardware this is.

The 32-bit / 64-bit issue is about what the basic word size of the hardware is, and the processor has instructions that use that size. So software built for 64-bit will be using those instructions, and would crash if you somehow got it to run on a 32-bit machine.

To do what you want, *if* you machine is 64-bit, then you could install a 64-bit linux, and then 64-bit JVM.